# Write a function which is given the day number, and it returns the day name (a string)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume the days of the week are numbered 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 from Sunday to Saturday. Write a function which is given the day number, and it returns the day name (a string).
Help me solve this tusk pls.
And explain me pls why my code return me mistake:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
d1 = "Понедельник"
d2 = "Вторник"
d3 = "Среда"
d4 = "Четверг"
d5 = "Пятница"
d6 = "Суббота"
d7 = "Воскресенье"

print (input ("Chose day of number: "))
x = int(input())

if x == 1:

       print (d1)

print("Program ended")
```

Comment: What was your input?

Comment: You're calling `input()` twice. Use `x = int(input("Choose day of number: "))`. Also, you should be using a list for the names of the days.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "Help me do my homework" is not a Stack Overflow issue -- this is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used the `input` function in the wrong way, please try something like this :

```
d1 = "Понедельник"
d2 = "Вторник"
d3 = "Среда"
d4 = "Четверг"
d5 = "Пятница"
d6 = "Суббота"
d7 = "Воскресенье"

x = int(input("Chose day of number: "))

if x == 1:
    print(d1)

print("Program ended")
```

I think you're a beginner. You can use `dict`, `list` etc. to make your program simpler.

Comment: Thanks you! You help me!

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary can be used for solving this requirement easily.

**Here is the working solution that uses the Python dictionary:**

```
# File name: Weekdays.py

weekDays = {
    1: "Понедельник",
    2: "Вторник",
    3: "Среда",
    4: "Четверг",
    5: "Пятница",
    6: "Суббота",
    7: "Воскресенье"
}


userInput = input("Choose a number for day (1 to 7): ")
if(userInput.isdigit() and (int(userInput) > 0) and (int(userInput) < 8)):
    n = int(userInput)
    print(weekDays[n])
else:
    print("Input must be a number between 1 and 7 only")
```

**Output:**

```
> python Weekdays.py
Choose a number for day (1 to 7): 6
Суббота

> python Weekdays.py
Choose a number for day (1 to 7): 1
Понедельник

> python Weekdays.py
Choose a number for day (1 to 7): 99
Input must be a number between 1 and 7 only

> python Weekdays.py
Choose a number for day (1 to 7): 0
Input must be a number between 1 and 7 only

> python Weekdays.py
Choose a number for day (1 to 7): 7
Воскресенье
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
def days_func(day_index):
    days = {0: 'Monday', 1: 'Tuesday', 2: 'Wednesday', 3: 'Thursday', 4: 'Friday', 5: 'Saturday', 6: 'Sunday'}

    if day_index in range(0, 6):
        return days[day_index]
    else:
        message = 'Invalid Number, try again!'
        return message


try:
    day = int(input('Enter the number of a day : '))
    print(days_func(day))
except ValueError:
    print('Index must be Integer!')
```

Comment: First of all you have an infinite loop there, second why not just use a list for `days`?

Comment: it's not an infinite loop, you can just enter a valid number and it continues.

Comment: If you enter an invalid number, say `7`, the `while day_index not in range(0, 6)` will run forever printing `Invalid number` as there is nothing stopping it from doing so. Maybe you meant `if day_index not in ...`?

Comment: I think you're right because the post owner didn't mention that he needs a loop, I should correct my answer.

Comment: Regardless of what OP is asking, this is an infinite loop **in case of a wrong input**. You might also add a `day_index = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 6: "))` inside the loop to make this more reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Error because of other character than digit as input.Try to use dictionary to store data and fetch it as requirement.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary

Comment: This answer is really unclear and vague. Try to be more specific and clear if you really want to help OP